# Can't use ngChange in ngRepeat - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ngRepeat to generate a fieldset of checkboxes.

I do this as follows:

```
<fieldset id="country_select" ng-controller="CountriesListController">
        <span ng-repeat="country in countries">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="country.name" ng-change="locationAdd(country.name)">
            {{country.name}}
          </label><br/>
        </span>
</fieldset>
```

However for some reason adding the ngChange directive to my checkbox causes my ng-repeat output to display only one checkbox as follows:

*checkbox*  {{country.name}}

When I change ngChange to ngClick my ngRepeat loop works.

So my question is: Why does ngChange not work with ngRepeat but ngClick does when inserted into my checkbox input

I get the following error in my console:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12)
at getControllers (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7535:19)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7724:33)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7073:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7076:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7076:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6952:30)
at $get.boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7091:16)
at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7747:18)
at ngRepeatAction (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:24524:15)angular.js:11592 (anonymous function)angular.js:8542 $getangular.js:14241 $get.Scope.$digestangular.js:14486 $get.Scope.$applyangular.js:9644 doneangular.js:9834 completeRequestangular.js:9775 requestLoaded
```

Comment: Check browser console for errors.

Comment: Please paste the whole code in jsfiddle

Comment: I have added my console error for you guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ng-change will require `ng-model`. You are missing ng-model on checkbox

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qJTwVH95ZIaZRd4lrfB9?p=preview) for working example.

Comment: Thank you for this! Do you perhaps know why ng-model is required by the ng-change directive?

Comment: All I see in Angular Documentation is: Note, this directive requires ngModel to be present.

Comment: It is required, because internally it is checking if a new value is committed for ng-model. If it is then only it will evaluate ng-change.Also, ng-model is required to maintain the control's state like dirty, invalid etc., which will be useful at the time of form-submit or ng-model is required, if you want to access the value of the selected checkboxes into scope.

Comment: Oh that makes complete sense. Thank you for teaching me a bit more about angular.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you intend to use `ngChange`. In my case, I was a bit too quick with the fingers and eyes and didn't catch Intellisense choosing `data-ng-change` when I intended to use `data-ng-click`

*I'm pretty sure I only saw one entry (data-ng-click) after typing `data-ng-c`; but maybe Intellisense was a bit slow in displaying the other options and picked the alphabetically first when I hit [Tab]...*